# Import library with Custom UI elements into Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, dll, enterprise-architect

I want to make own `UI control` in c# and save it as `dll`. After that I want to import this `library` to the `Enterprise Architect`. It is possible? Maybe I can make other way?
I know about `MDG` technology, but there are some problems when I'm modifying the appearance of `stereotype`.
I also want to make the field "name" be more flexible - how to move it inside control?
So it is possible to import dll with custom controls to the `EA` or maybe some tips how to increase `MDG`?.

Comment: There is an option to register your DLL as an addin. What do you mean in 'control'? custom model element?

Comment: I want to create own library with custom UI controls. After that I want to place it in EA Diagram (like class elements or Win32 UI), it (my control - it can be "button") should be visible on the EA diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use your own UI controls in EA. You can either launch them as popup from our add-in code, or you can use `Repository.Window` or `Repository.AddTab` to add your control in a docked window, or the main diagram tab.

You can find a simple working example using a docked window on my [github repository](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/tree/master/MyAddin)

A more elaborate example is the [EA Navigator](http://bellekens.com/ea-navigator/) for which you can find the code on [github](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Toolpack) as well.

Comment: And it is possible to place new controls from docked window on the EA diagram?

Comment: @ŁukaszBoryczka I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "place new controls from docked window in the EA diagram"

Comment: Yes there is the ability to add your own controls to the Add-ins window. It can be found under Extensions->Add-in Windows. http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/automation_and_scripting/custom_docked_window.html

Comment: @GeertBellekens, I just want to push mouse button on my control in docked window and place in on the EA diagram - I want to make this control visible on the EA diagram. I made some "visualisation": [Image](http://i.imgur.com/ywZ2Q4z.png).

Comment: @ŁukaszBoryczka Ah, now I see what you mean. No in that case docked windows are not useful. You'll have to use MDG technology to define your stereotypes and toolboxes, and you'll have to provide either a shapescript or an alternate image for the controls that use one of your stereotypes. There are ways to mix add-ins with MDG technology, for instance if you want to do complex transformations, but I'm not sure if that will help in your case.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, thank you for the answer. MDG doesn't resolve the problem in 100%, but probably I have to use it.